# Sidecar AIR Runtime install with Native .exe installer using ADT

Tags: flash, air, adobe, native, adt

I have packaged my AIR app into a Native .exe installer using ADT. If the user does not have air installed and they are connected to the internet, the AIR runtime is automatically installed.

Is it possible to package the AIR runtime into the exe so that if the user is not online the AIR runtime is installed?

I have experimented with the sidecar install and .air file but ideally I want to only have the one file(.exe). I already have a distribution licence from Adobe.

AIR 2.0+

Thanks, James.

Answer (score 0):

You need to package the side-car installer using a third-party installer creator to create the executable.

[NSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) is probably the most popular, free installer for windows. Windows includes the [IExpress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress) tool for creating standalone installers, however it seems to have trouble with the side-car directory structure and may require an intermediate packager (such as self-extracting archive), or a custom installation definition file. [WIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) is an alternative for creating MSI installers.

Mac OS-X includes [PackageMaker](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for creating self-extracting installers.

[Wikipedia lists many free and commercial installer creators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software).